# Google Maps api v3 - Controls hidden in default tablet Android browser

Tags: browser, google-maps-api-3, android

I found strange problem. I used [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3) basic example of google maps. This maps works on all browsers except on default browser in my Samsung GalaxyTab (Honecomb 3.1). In this browser there are hidden controls. Or controls have bad z-index. If I move with map, I can see them for a while. There is no problem in default browser in Android 2.3, in Firefox on tablet, or any other browsers. Does anyone have solution for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered this bug today as well, but I'm trying to get an element float on top of a google maps element. I found a fix at: https://github.com/CloudMade/Leaflet/issues/335 and that is to add:

```
 .gmnoprint {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);  
 }
```

This forces the element to be on top, for some really odd reason. The line above works for the built in zoom controls etc on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and can of course be applied to all elements that should be on top.

Comment: Thanks! It helped! Also if you have custom controls, add this line to css file: `.controls{
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); 
 }`